# How to find determinant of the matrix $N\times N$

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to find determinant of the matrix NxN?
$$
 \left| \begin{array}{ccccc}
a^{n} & (a - 1)^{n} & \cdots & (a-n)^{n} \\
a^{n - 1} & (a - 1)^{n - 1} & \cdots & (a-n)^{n - 1} \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots
\\
a & a - 1 & \cdots & a-n\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{array} \right|
$$

Comment: That appears to be a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix...

Comment: There is N = (n + 1)

Comment: Hint: look up the formula for determinants of Vandermonde matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the article for [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)!

Comment: Good job you beat me to this answer by about four seconds.